# Passing BootstrapFormHelpers DATE PICKER with POST

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding passing the value of the formhelpers date picker with POST. Please help me on how to post this. I can successfully post the values with  tags

so this is the html markup,

```
<label for="delivDate" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><font color="black">DELIVERY DATE</font></label>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
          <div id="deliveryDate" name="deliveryDate" class="bfh-datepicker" data-date="today"></div>
     </div>
```

So I need to pass the selected date value so that I can see the value with var_dump($_POST). Please help me

Answer (score 1):

```
--HTML--
<input type="text" placeholder="Select Date" style="width:200px; float:left;"            class="input-xlarge datepicker" id="dateSearch" name="date"  onChange="parseDate();" > 

--jQuery--
<script>
function parseDate() {
$( "#dateSearch" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" ); 
}
</script>
<script>
var dateValue = $('#dateSearch').val();
alert(dateValue );
</script>
```